# cloudfront fail to request objects in behavior

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have setup cloudfront, elb and my ec2 web server for default behavior (no caching), everything is working fine. There is only 1 origin (the elb) and the origin path is empty.
Now I want to cache static stuff with cloudfront from the web server (wildfly) like js/css, they're all served in /my-context/assets folder

So i add a new behavior with path pattern '/my-context/assets/*' and default cache settings using the same origin. 
This is not working, my request login page return the page html itself, but all css/js are failed. Request to /my-context/assets/a/b/some.css return 502 with "CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin."

I also tried to setup a new origin (with the same elb) with path "/my-context/assets" for the new behavior, it also fail.

Can I have instruction on how to make this work? or is this actually not do-able?

Thank you!

Comment: You definitely don't need a second origin, and setting the origin path to anything *prepends* the origin path to the request-path sent by the browser, so you don't want that, either.  In the first scenario (2 behaviors, 1 origin) did you have the `Host:` header whitelisted on the new behavior you wanted to enable for caching?

Comment: I'll post that as an answer, if you will confirm -- you needed to whitelist the `Host:` header in the new behavior, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to configure the cache behavior to forward (whitelist) the `Host:` header to the origin, from the incoming request.

This is not to imply that it's the "correct" configuration in every case, but many times it is desirable, or even required.

When CloudFront makes a back-end https connection to your origin server, the certificate offered by the server has to not only be valid (not expired, not self-signed, issued by a trusted CA, and with an intact intermediate chain) *but also* has to be valid *for the request CloudFront will be sending*.

> For CloudFront to use HTTPS when communicating with your origin, one of the domain names in the certificate must match one or both of the following values:
>
> • The value that you specified for Origin Domain Name for the applicable origin in your distribution.
>
> • If you configured CloudFront to forward the Host header to your origin, the value of the Host header.
>
> The SSL/TLS certificate on your origin includes a domain name in the Common Name field and possibly several more in the Subject Alternative Names field. (CloudFront supports wildcard characters in certificate domain names.) If your certificate doesn't contain any domain names that match either Origin Domain Name or the domain name in the Host header, CloudFront returns an HTTP status code 502 (Bad Gateway) to the viewer.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#SecureConnectionsHowToRequireCustomProcedure

In your case, you originally were running requests through CloudFront with caching disabled, which is typically done by configuring CloudFront to forward all request headers to the origin, as this automatically disables caching of responses.

Later, when you attempted configure a second cache behavior so that objects matching certain path patterns could be cached, you naturally did not forward all headers to the origin -- but in this case, forwarding the `Host:` header (which CloudFront refers to as "whitelisting" the header for forwarding) was necessary, because CloudFront appeared to have needed that information in order to validate the certificate that the origin server was presenting.

If you don't forward the `Host:` header, the the certificate must match the Origin Domain Name, as noted above, and in your case, this us apparently not the case.  If the `Host:` header is not whitelisted for forwarding, then CloudFront still sends a host header in the back-end request, but this header is set to the same value as Origin Domain Name, hence the reason the certificate must match that value.

If matching one way or the other were not required (along with all the other conditions CloudFront imposes on HTTPS connections to the origin), this would prevent CloudFront from determining with reasonable certainty that the back end connection was being handled by the intended server, and that the origin server is genuinely the server it claims to be, which is one of two protections provided by TLS/SSL (the other protection, of course, is the actual encryption of traffic).