# CLOUDFRONT EC2 origin error CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudfront distribution with custom origin (EC2), When I am fetching the file like http://xyz.cloudfront.net/assets/abcd.jpg

I am getting error like

```
The request could not be satisfied.

CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection.
CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin. 

Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: cDjvMwhz6AhjwOyTgEqwH6KPA3X97Zq1GXQLtvdUlkAWIUDmUAincA==
```

but after 10-15 mins if i try to fetch rom same url then I works fine, then if I fetch new url same things happen. I don't understand what is the problem here why first time fetching the new file is generating error?

EDIT

The problem is with https, I have changed the cloudfront distribution to serve https only now the cloudfront always return "The request could not be satisfied."

My server is configured correctly i can able to access it with https

I don't want to use custom CNAME, the dns name provided by cloudfront is okay, I just want to serve assets on https only, Is there any custom ssl requirement on cloudfront for this?

Comment: What do you see in the logs on the origin server?

Comment: I cant see any log for this on my origin server, but I got the issue, problem is with https, when the request is made through https then the cloud front return "The request could not be satisfied."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot do i need to add custom ssl on cloudfront distribution for this?

Comment: Okay... so, does your origin server actually support https?  What is the http error code returned by CloudFront?

Comment: yes my server is supporting https and its working fine, and cloudfront is returning this "CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin. "

Comment: Your origin's SSL certificate must match the origin hostname you configured, or the `Host:` header that CloudFront is sending to the origin, which will be the same value unless [configured otherwise](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35258911/1695906) and your origin cannot have a self-signed certificate or an invalid chain.  Can you mention the origin hostname you're using?

Comment: thanks for your help, i had invalid chain thats what causing the all error, I fixed it and everything worked. :)

Comment: @ayushlodhi Can u please tell me. What is mean by Invalid chain..?? Because now am also facing this issue..???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had invalid certificate chain thats is what causing all the trouble.

Comment: Can you please share how did you fix it?

Comment: @Salik just follow the instructions provided by your certificate provider.

Comment: Am using the Certify the web in my instance for free SSL for my subdomain(img.xxx.in). For This subdomain i created cloudfront distribution with aws cretificate manager. After change in my DNS -  A to CNAME. Its throwing this error.

Comment: If I Revert the DNS CNAME to A. It will work from my IIS server. Not from cloud front distribution. Please give me a solution.