# Use what Origin and ServerName for SSL certificate between CloudFront and EC2 Origin?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I want to set up an HTTPS connection between a Cloudfront Web Distribution and a single EC2 origin server.  I've studied this [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517500/how-to-set-ssl-between-cloudfront-as-a-reverse-proxy-cache-with-an-ec2-custom-or) but I still need help.  My domain name, "www.newb.com", is pointing at Cloudfront by using Route 53 and that connection has an SSL certificate from ACM.

So that's good but I also need to secure the connection between CloudFront and my EC2 origin.  I presently have CloudFront pointing at ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com - my origin server.

When I try to get an SSL certificate for ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com, Gandi and Certbot return errors.  For instance, Certbot says "Error creating new authz :: Policy forbids issuing for name".  Assuming I can't get an SSL certificate on Amazon's ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX name, I need to know what DNS name to use and how to configure CloudFront and my server.

The discussion above references a subdomain name, for instance, like "origin.newb.com" for me.  If that's the type of name I should get an SSL certificate for:

1) where do I point CloudFront at?  to "origin.newb.com" or still to ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX or something else?

2) when I configure apache's port 443 listeners, what do I set ServerName to?

3) if ACM has already issued an SSL certificate for www.newb.com, will a second SSL certificate from Certbot for "origin.newb.com" create any problems?

My EC2 is a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS LAMP server.  A single origin server will be enough for my use case and I don't want to pay for an ELB.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. Cloudfront has to point as custom origin to "origin.newb.com"
2. The ServerName in the Sites available configuration is origin.newb.com
3. I have issued multiple certificates on sub domains there is no issue with that.Remember you can create wildcard certificate also Example : *.newb.com
   and use it for both the subdomains.

Comment: So how do CloudFront and my EC2 server "know" that "origin.newb.com" is really ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX?  The CloudFront documentation says:  "If your origin is an HTTP server, type the domain name of the resource. The files must be publicly available."  Do I set ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX as a CNAME in CloudFront?  I guess I'm confused about how CloudFront and my EC2 server would match "origin.newb.com" up with the Public DNS ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.  The folks here at newb.com thank you!

Comment: Create a new record set in the Route 53 with sub domain name and A type record with iPV4.Set-Alias as no and the value is the IP of the instance.

Comment: Ahhh.  So I'd put in at least these Route 53 Record Sets:  1-"www.newb.com A ALIAS d31XX.cloudfront.net" 2-"www.newb.com AAAA ALIAS d31XX.cloudfront.net" and 3-"origin.newb.com A [Elastic IP]"?  So that way, when I point CloudFront at "origin.newb.com" CF will "know" that the origin server is my EC2 Elastic IP?  That makes sense.  TY