# Nginx Redirect to EC2 Instance

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I had angular (version: 7) site which was deployed on S3 bucket, but for SEO purposes, recently I integrated [Angular Universal](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter).

Now I moved site/frontend from S3 bucket to EC2 instance. I am trying to deploy my angular universal application on Nginx (version: nginx/1.14.1) on my EC2 instance (CentOS).

The flow goes something like domain-name(example.com/www.example.com) is registered on godaddy which points out to Cloud Front which sends/forward my request to EC2 instance (Nginx server).

**Issue**

Whenever I try to hit the urls https://example.com or https://www.example.com, they got redirected to EC2 instance address like https://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.region-x.compute.amazonaws.com/ .

Someone figured out that it is due to server configuration, as stated [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33138199/3084228)

> Be sure, when you connect through CloudFront, that the server doesn't
>   redirect you back to the EC2 hostname or IP (the address bar in the
>   browser will change, if it does, and you'll want to fix your web
>   server's config if that happens).

So it seems like I have nginx configuration issue. Following are the confurations I used.

**EC2 Security Group Settings**

[image: EC2 Security Group]

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream nrc_frontend_nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate ssl/example.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/example.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'CEMDH+ATSGCM:EDH+AESGCG:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    root /home/ec2-user/nginx/dist; # <-- Static Resources

   # Load configuration files for the default server block.
   include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri @backend; # <--- This looks for requests (statics i.e js/css/fonts)
                                      # in /ssr/dist folder. If nothing found, calls @backend (running at 127.0.0.1:4000)
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://nrc_frontend_nodejs;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}
```

Its been couple of days, I have tried many different ways to configure the nginx, but no luck so far. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you whitelist HOST header on CloudFront in cache based on Selected header configuration ?

Comment: @JamesDean, I have added HOST header to whitelist header list on CloudFront Distribution, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name yourdomaim.com;

    location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5200;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

You should run your angular universal project on port 5200, using tools like pm2 if you are using nodeJS. And the about settings should work in nginx

Comment: 1) What's the reason for port 5200? 2) And what will be value for `root` (folder)?