# Why cloudfront cannot map EC2 DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I was installing website in my EC2 and its DNS is `ec2-x-x-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com`. When I add that EC2 DNS in Cloudfront Origin Domain, it was not working. Because website could be open when I type **http://ec2-x-x-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com** in browser. I need to type **http://ec2-x-x-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/uxp/rt/html/login.html?locale=en-us** in browser. That's why it can be configured in Cloudfront. That's why please let me know how to configure Cloudfront like that?

Comment: Cloudfront to point EC2 you have to use load balancer. It cannot be directly point to DNS.

Comment: see this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137792/cloudfront-and-ec2

Answer (score 0):

Point your CloudFront to an Application Load Balancer, and the Application Load Balancer to your EC2 instance. You can't point a CloudFront distro directly to an EC2 instance.